# Logging errors in different files based on type of exception using Log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using log4j for logging.

Tried using custom log levels in log4j with no success.
This is something like my `log4j.properties`

```
log4j.logger.com.some.services.Class1=ERROR1, Appender1
log4j.logger.com.some.services.Class1=ERROR2, Appender2
log4j.appender.Appender1.File=${SOME_PATH}/log1.log
log4j.appender.Appender2.File=${SOME_PATH}/log2.log
```

And using custom log levels like this:-

```
private static final Level ERROR1= Level.forName("ERROR1", 50);
private static final Level ERROR2= Level.forName("ERROR2", 150);
.
.
. 
try
{
 ...
}
catch(Exception1 e1)
{
// log in log1.log file
  logger.log(ERROR1, "Some message");
}
catch(Exception2 e2)
{
// log in log2.log file
  logger.log(ERROR2, "Another message");
}
```

Comment: Use markers and have different appenders that can grab different markers.

Comment: Also do you have to use log4j or can you use the newer log4j 2?